# c# : How to make a bitmap transparent

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, transparent

```
Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);

Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(LoadPath);
Image img2 = Bitmap.FromFile(TempPath);

g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
g.DrawImage(img2, 250, 250);
```

'img' and 'img2' are an image with transparent parts.
When I run the code, transparent parts appear in black.
Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Try setting the form `IsMdiContainer` to `false`

Comment: It works fine, the rounded corners are clearly visible.  Pretty unclear what else you expected.  Consider Graphics.Clear() to initialize the *tmp* bitmap with a color other than black.

Comment: Make the target bitmap transparent first: g.Clear(Color.Transparent);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look here

```
private void MakeTransparent_Example1(PaintEventArgs e)
{

// Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.gif");

// Draw myBitmap to the screen.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width,
    myBitmap.Height);

// Make the default transparent color transparent for myBitmap.
myBitmap.MakeTransparent();

// Draw the transparent bitmap to the screen.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myBitmap.Width, 0,
    myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
}
```

Comment: Wow.Such an easy way. Thank you for the contribution. @Eak Team

Comment: Suppose one of the images he used has portions matching the default color of the bitmap. Would this color than be made transparent, too?

Comment: `MakeTransparent();` before `Graphics.DrawImage`